# DnsGetHostEntry gets wrong IP address

Tags: c#, sockets

I have the following problem. I try to bon a socket via the `socket.Bind()` function. But it always throws up. I guess its because it gets the internal ip from the

`IPHostEntry ipHe = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());`

function. I think this probelm is caused by my static IP. `Ipconfig /all` shows my Ip is like `109.90.xxx.xxx` and the Ip the program gets is `192.168.xxx.xxx`.

The Error it throws is "The requested address is not valid in its context"

Comment: may be you have a router in your home metwork? Or it's look like you have a VPN network connection with LAN...

Answer (score 0):

There is likely to be more than one ip address associated with your host.  Try looping through the list of returned ip addresses.

```
foreach (IPAddress ip in ipHe.AddressList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("    {0}", ip);
}
```

Comment: there is only one ip 192.168.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 0):

`Dns.GetHostEntry` queries DNS, so it's possible that it's wrong there. From a command prompt, what does `nslookup {your hostname}` return?

Basically, there's nothing to stop DNS and your local machine being out of step. This may be on purpose or it may indicate a problem, and will depend on your local network requirements and config.

In order to get the local IP address independently of DNS, then you need to query the interfaces directly: look at `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`, which you can then enumarate and call `GetIPProperties()` on each, which returns both multicast and unicast IP addresses.

Comment: 'nslookup
Default Server:  cns1.cw.net
Address:  141.1.1.1'

how can i define the Interface my programm shoud use ? I get via GetAllNetworkInterfaces() a bunch of intefaces but it seems its using the correct interface but just getting the wrong address